# PIL: How to get palette index for RGB?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I want to iterate over all pixels of a given color in a PNG image (that I create with [imagemagick](/questions/tagged/imagemagick)). The iterating part I can handle, but that image uses a color palette, so I need to get the palette index for the given color, in my case white. Normally this should work with the function `ImagePalette.getcolor()`, but that tells me that the palette is in raw mode which I don't know how to disable. What I do is below, but there has to be a simpler way.

```py
        import sys
        from PIL import Image
        import numpy as np

        image = Image.open( sys.argv[1] )
        width, height = image.size
        # image.palette.getcolor( (255,255,255) ) # gives ValueError: palette contains raw palette data
        palette = image.getpalette() # a list
        palette = np.reshape( palette, (-1, 3) )
        #rows255, _cols255 = np.where( palette == (255,255,255) ) # gives the same as below - apparently or'ing
        rows255, _cols255 = np.where( palette == 255 )
        whites = []
        count = 1
        prev = -1
        for r in rows255:
            if r==prev:
                count += 1
            else:
                count = 1
            if count==3:
                whites.append( prev )
            prev = r

        print(whites)
```

So I'm interested in either doing this directly with [pil](/questions/tagged/pil) or using `numpy.where()` for tuples correctly.

The situation should be the same with every image with palette, but this is one of my files: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WRld.jpg

Comment: Kindly post the *"unhappy"* image.

Comment: Are you trying to count the white pixels? If so, you'd probably be better off thresholding and then counting non-zero pixels.

Comment: I'm trying to count all pixels that satisfy a criterion that I cannot check on the image, so I need all (x,y) coordinates of white pixels so that I can further evaluate.

Comment: Also, can you explain the criterion you are looking for please? There may be a better way to find whatever it is that you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain what your question really is, nor what you are trying to do. I think you want to get the index of the palette entry that corresponds to white.

```
# Open image
image = Image.open('image.png')

# Extract palette and reshape to 256x3 RGB entries
palette = image.getpalette()
palette = np.reshape( palette, (-1, 3) )
```

This then tells you which palette entries are white, namely the first and last:

```
np.all(palette==255,axis=-1)

Out[34]: 
array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False,  True])
```

Or maybe you want this, which tells you the same thing, namely that the first and last entries are white:

```
np.where(np.all(palette==255,axis=-1)) 

Out[35]: (array([  0, 255]),)
```